# How do I do this in Sql? Loop? Multi-Insert?

Tags: sql

This is the DB Schema:

```
PC
- id (pri key)
- model
- name

Laptop
- id (pri key)
- model
- name
```

How do I get for each unique(model) laptop, how do I insert it into PC with model number + 1? (+1 because I know insert into might work but the prob I need won't be solved with insert into)

Any clue?

---

Elaboration:

For each unique (based on model column) Laptop record that we have, we want to create a PC record in which the model column for the PC would be +1 of the model column in laptop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here. Do you want to import the records from Laptop into PC?

Comment: You really need to explain better what you are looking for. The question is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

+1 doesn't stop "INSERT INTO" from working:

```
INSERT INTO PC
    ( Model, Name )
SELECT DISTINCT Model + 1, Name
FROM Laptop
```

Comment: Just a hunch, because the question is hard to understand, but I think the OP added the +1 because they thought somehow that using the same model number would make the insert fail. I think that was a workaround and they didn't necessarily want the model number to be +1.

Answer (score 0):

This was mentioned in the comments by jrockway and is probably your best bet if you plan to keep the 1-1 relationship of laptops to PCs with a +1 model number.

Drop the laptop table altogether and just create the following view (Assuming SQL Server):

```
CREATE VIEW PC
AS
SELECT  ID,Model+1 as Model, Name
FROM Laptop
```

This way you don't have to manage and keep two table synchronized.